# Is the curve smooth?

Tags: algebraic-curves

Are  the plane curves

$C: X^5+Y^5+Z^5+(X^2+Y^2)Z^3 $

and

$D: X^5+Y^5+(X^2+Y^2)Z^3$

smooth or not?

It seems $D$ has only a node at $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: I assume by "plane curves" you mean in the projective plane $\Bbb{P}^2$?

Comment: Check "locally": set one of the variables (say $z$) equal to 1 to look in an affine chart, and then check the "Jacobian criterion". Look at the Jacobian/gradient $dC = \left( \frac{\partial C}{\partial x}, \, \frac{\partial C}{\partial y}\right)$, and make sure it is not the zero vector for any of the points on the curve.

Comment: Thanks Nick for the process. I checked D is a nodal curve as you said. But just wanted to make sure of the curve D if it is smooth if I am not wrong.

Comment: If it has a node, then it is not smooth. A "node" is by definition a singularity.